# How do I merge two adjacent <span> together if they have the same class?

Tags: jquery

Currently I have a `<p>` with processed matched word that are wrapped by `<span class="matched">`.

> Hello, how is your day today?

```css
.matched{
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<p>Hello, <span class="matched">how</span> is your <span class="matched">day</span><span class="matched"> today</span>?</p>
```

to

```css
.matched{
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<p>Hello, 
<span class="matched">how</span> is your <span class="matched">day today</span>?</p>
```

The word **how**, **day**, and **today** are the matched word that are wrapped in `<span class="matched">` and how do I merge a `<span class="matched">` tag when its next html element also has a `<span class="matched">` into one single ''?

Thank you very much guys~ =)

Edit: *This doesn't change the result but I want my source to look better.*

Comment: What do you want to achieve after they are merged?

Comment: @Ihazkode want to merge current <span> with adjacent <span> together into one <span> if they have the same class name. If no, skip.

Comment: Yes, I understood that part, I meant *after* the matched terms are merged into one `<span>` what is the intended use?

Comment: I don't know of any tools that will do this for you.

Comment: @Ihazkode because I will need to  push the newly merged `<span>` 's into an array for other non visual purposes

Comment: @kpie oh, thanks for the edit there~

Comment: @kpie not even with jQuery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following is one way to do it. Note that I've used the standard DOM properties [`.nextSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nextSibling) and [`.nodeType`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType) because for this problem you have to take text nodes into account, but jQuery DOM navigation methods tend to skip over text nodes.

```js
var matchedArr = $("span.matched").get()  // Select all .matched as array
var $current, next, $next
while (matchedArr.length > 0 ) {          // While there are unprocessed ones left
  current = matchedArr.shift()            // Take from front of array
  while(next = current.nextSibling) {     // While that element has a next sibling
    if (next.nodeType === 1) {            // that is an element (not a text node)
      var $next = $(next)                 // get next as jQuery object
      if ($next.is("span.matched")) {     // check if it has the class
        // Add to the HTML of the current element
        // (don't use .append() or you'll add separate text nodes):
        $(current).html(function(i, content) { return content + $next.remove().html() })
        matchedArr.shift()    // remove *next* element from start of array so
                              // that it won't be processed separately
        continue              // continue inner loop to check for more siblings
      } 
    }
    break                     // break inner loop because the next sibling didn't match
  }
}

// check results:
$("p").each(function() { console.log(this.innerHTML) })
```

```css
.matched{
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>Hello, <span class="matched">how</span> is your <span class="matched">day</span><span class="matched"> today</span>?</p>

<p>A test where <span class="matched">several</span><span class="matched"> elements</span><span class="matched"> in</span><span class="matched"> a</span><span class="matched"> row</span> have the class, but also <span class="matched">some</span><span> have</span> non-matching elements <span class="matched">after</span><span class="matched"> them</span>.</p>
```

Note that the `matchedArr.shift()` on the line before `continue` in the inner loop is because at that point the first element in the array is the next sibling that we've just combined into `current`, so we `.shift()` that element out of the array so that we don't try to process it on the next iteration of the outer loop. (Note that `$("span.matched")` selects elements in the order they appear in the document.)

Comment: Oh, sorry for the late reply. It works wonderfully. Thank you very much for the solution and the detailed documentation~!!!